# Does SIP offer a mechanism to initiate a stream and returning an error?

Tags: sip, telephony

Imagine you are browsing to a HTTP URL that does not exists. You'll get a 404 which often contains an explanatory body.

Now imagine you are calling someone using VoIP with SIP and use a non-existent addressee. Is it possible to return an error AND to establish an RTP stream with an explanatory audio message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you look at the RFC at https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt 
It explains exactly how to do this.

> 20.18 Error-Info
>
> The Error-Info header field provides a pointer to additional
>     information about the error status response.
>
> ```
>   SIP UACs have user interface capabilities ranging from pop-up
>   windows and audio on PC softclients to audio-only on "black"
>   phones or endpoints connected via gateways.  Rather than forcing a
>   server generating an error to choose between sending an error
>   status code with a detailed reason phrase and playing an audio
>   recording, the Error-Info header field allows both to be sent.
>   The UAC then has the choice of which error indicator to render to
>   the caller.
> ```
>
> A UAC MAY treat a SIP or SIPS URI in an Error-Info header field as if
>     it were a Contact in a redirect and generate a new INVITE, resulting
>     in a recorded announcement session being established.  A non-SIP URI
>     MAY be rendered to the user.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  SIP/2.0 404 The number you have dialed is not in service
>  Error-Info: <sip:not-in-service-recording@atlanta.com>
> ```

The client would therefore receive the 404 in the SIP reply plus it will be told to connect to sip:not-in-service-recording@atlanta.com for a recorded message.